# How to select a row based on the color of some column in selenium

Tags: testing, selenium

I am selecting a row in a loop as its a dynamic table. Now I have to select a value in a drop down of one column based on the bgcolor of another column. Can any one please tell how to do this.

Following is the html of td

```html
<td bgcolor="#ffbf00" align="center" width="12px" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="whitetext" id="cars_0_tbl_Price_0_0">  4</td>
```

or

```html
<td bgcolor="Green" align="center" width="12px" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="whitetext" id="cars_2_tbl_Price_0_0"> 23</td>
```

and following is the html of td that i want to select based on the value of previous td

```html
<select style="width: 180px;" class="dropdowncommon" id="engine">
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML tag of the object(s)?

Comment: Which selenium are you using? IDE, RC, or WebDriver?

Comment: Not really that clear what you are trying to do.  We need to see the HTML for the select and options and a clear example of what you are trying to do.  (e.g. I want to see what colour column 2's background is and then select the same colour from the select box in column 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the following code helpful.

```
if (selenium.getAttribute("td@bgcolor").equalsIgnoreCase("Green")){

   // Perform desired action
}
```